# Reading multiple .csv files C#

Tags: c#

I've a program where i need to read in multiple .csv files from a directory, take some info from each one and then create one large .csv file. However i'm having problems reading them in but not sure why. I have this piece of code in my main method:

```
string sourceDirectory = @"sourceDirectory/test";

        var csvFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string currentFile in csvFiles)
        {
            readFile(currentFile);
        }
```

And then the following in my readFile method:

```
    public static void readFile(string currentFile)
            {   
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"destinationFile.csv");
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(currentFile);


                 while(**){
                    object[] array;
                    array = new object[11];

                    array[0] = info1;
                    array[1] = info2;
                    array[2] = info3;
                    //........

                    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
                }

                reader.DiscardBufferedData();
                writer.Close();
                reader.Close();
```

Without the while loop it only reads in one line of the file, understanably. I can't seem to understand what or even if the while loop should contain. If it was a .txt file i would simply put `while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)`. My code never seems to read in more than one .csv file from the direcotry but there are 6 .csv files in there.

The only data i really need from them is to count certain lines between dates(one of the .csv columns).

Comment: Yes, you read a line and then split at comma that line to create  the array. However, I suggest you to use a specific class called [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) that could help you to simplify your code.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: Please don't parse/write CSV by hand. Use a library. There are subtle rules that you don't get right which WILL be a pain for many developers later on when they need to use malformed CSV. Even such a simple format causes so much pain...

Comment: @KarelTamayo will have a look, thanks!

Comment: @KarelTamayo having read the CsvHelper it's very useful but doesn't help me in reading multiple csv files?